# Js regexp question match

Tags: javascript, regex

I am just starting to learn js and I got stuck to regexp at a specific expression. Can you figure out what `!![a-z]*` will match ? 
I can't seem to figure this one out.

Comment: This is not JavaScript specific.

Answer (score 4):

You should really consider reading how regular expressions work. Have a look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html.

That would match 2 exclamation marks (!) followed any number of letters from a to z.

Answer (score 1):

Two exclamation marks followed by any number (including 0) of characters from a to z.

Answer (score 0):

```
'!!abcdefgh$asd124123'.match(/!![a-z]*/g)
return ["!!abcdefgh"]

'!!#abcdefgh$asd124123'.match(/!![a-z]*/g)

return ['!!']
```

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some context around your source-code. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.